# (Help Please) Type The method initilizeMap() is undefined for the type Fragment1

Tags: android, methods, maps, fragment

I have created an app with a swipe view using fragments. Everything about that is fine. The problem comes when I try to uso Google Maps on a fragment. It gives me the error: "Type The method initilizeMap() is undefined for the type Fragment1". I am stuck please help me.

The part of the code of the fragment:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);







        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

            // Changing map type
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
            // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
            // googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);

            // Showing / hiding your current location
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            // Enable / Disable zooming controls
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);

            // Enable / Disable my location button
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

            // Enable / Disable Compass icon
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

            // Enable / Disable Rotate gesture
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);

            // Enable / Disable zooming functionality
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add somewhere in your code initilizeMap() as this is not predefined somewhere.